# How do i locate where a program is installed on Linux without knowing its exact executable name?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to locate where a program's executable file is located from the command line.  Is there any way to do that without knowing the executable's exact name?

Ive tried whereis "program name"  --- doesn't return anything

dpkg -query -L 'program name' -- requires exact package name

any other ways to do this?

Comment: On deb-based systems (debian, ubuntu) `apt-cache search search_string` if you know at least part of the program name or description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two choices.

**First:**

```
apropos partial_name
```

It will bring a name and description of every program that contains *partial_name*. It requires that the program has a *man* page.

For example:

```
apropos lsp
```

brings:

```
git-mailsplit (1)    - Simple UNIX mbox splitter program
lspci (8)            - list all PCI devices
lspgpot (1)          - extracts the ownertrust values from PGP keyrings
```

**Second:**

```
locate partial_name
```

It will bring a list of executables, config files, man pages that contains *partial_name*. It could be very long, you will need to filter the results.